# np-complete but not "hard"

Tags: runtime, np-complete, np-hard, asymptotic-complexity

Is there some language that is NP-complete but for which we know some "quick" algorithm?  I don't mean like the ones for knapsack where we can do well on average, I mean that even in the worst case the runtime is something like 2^n^epsilon, where the result holds for any epsilon>0 and so we can allow it to get arbitrarily close to 0.

Comment: I was able to determinine that this question was easily googlable  homework in O(2^n^0.01) time.

Comment: @msw: provide a source or roll back, please.

Comment: @danben: I guess the joke was lost on you.

Comment: @Mike Atlas: I guess so; please explain the joke where you tag other people's posts as "homework" without verification.

Comment: Yes, this always bothers me.  This seems like it could be a homework question, or it could be someone wondering about something she read.  I don't want to do people's homework, but I am happy to satisfy curiosity if I can, and I sometimes learn something too.  On the other hand, I sometimes think SO is used as a crutch for those trying to learn a language on their own, but leaving the deep thinking to others.

Comment: @WhirlWind - generally I will just ask the OP to tag the post themselves if it is in fact homework.  This seems to work well - they'll either tag it or say that it isn't, which I think is good enough.  The exception is when someone pastes a problem verbatim from their assignment (which is easily identifiable anyway).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), "There are also decision problems that are NP-hard but not NP-complete, for example the halting problem."

There are no languages that are NP complete where we know a "quick" algorithm; otherwise, it wouldn't be NP-complete.

Answer (score 3):

If you do find a "quick" algorithm to this np-complete problem, you just solved that 
P=NP, and as you know, that is still an open question.